# Bash Backup script: Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, backup, scp

I have written a backup script for my linux machine that encrypts the tarball and sends it to a remote server with scp with configured ssh key pairs, but it gives me the following error when i run it: `./backup_script.sh: line 27: /home/zero/Backup/backup_20230731_1251.tar.gz.gpg: Permission denied`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the date format for the filename
datetime=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M")

# Define the source directory and the backup directory
src_dir="/var/www/html" # this is the directory that we will back up
backup_dir="/home/zero/Backup" # This is where we will temporarily store the encrypted backup data

# Create a tarball of the source directory
tar -czf $backup_dir/backup_$datetime.tar.gz $src_dir

# Read the password from a secure file
password=$(cat /home/zero/Backup/pwd)

# Encrypt the tarball using openssl
gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase $password --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --output $backup_dir/backup_$datetime.tar.gz.gpg $backup_dir/backup_$datetime.tar.gz

rm $backup_dir/backup_$datetime.tar.gz

# Get the .gpg filename 
filename=$(find /home/zero/Backup -type f -name "*.gpg" -print -quit)

# Check if a file was found
if [ -n "$filename" ]; then
    # if file is found send it ove ssh to the remote server
    send=scp $filename root@178.79.148.186:/root/Backup
        echo "$(date): Backup Successful" >> /home/zero/Backup/backup.log
    # remove file once it has been sent to remote server
    rm -f $filename
else
    # if file is not found display error msg 
    echo "$(date): No encrypted file found" >> /home/zero/Backup/backup.log
fi
```

The backup is made successfully, and the encryption works perfectly but it wont send to the remote server. I made the script in the root profile and i am running it as root. Here are the file permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 zero zero  4096 Jul 31 12:51 .
drwx------ 37 zero zero  4096 Jul 31 12:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3578 Jul 31 12:50 backup_20230731_1250.tar.gz.gpg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3578 Jul 31 12:51 backup_20230731_1251.tar.gz.gpg
-rw-r--r--  1 zero zero    96 Jul 31 12:51 backup.log
-rwx------  1 root root  1465 Jul 31 12:51 backup_script.sh
-rw-------  1 root root     5 Jul 29 04:13 pwd
```

My question is: How do i make it send to the remote server?

I have tried changing file permissions but i have had no luck.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the offending line.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Answer (score 2):

This is the fix i have come up with in the end. Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76803519/20177543 mentioning that it doesn't have execute permissions

```
# Check if a file was found
if [ -n "$filename" ]; then
    # if file is found send it over ssh to the remote server
    chmod +x $filename
    scp $filename root@178.79.xxx.xxx:/root/Backup
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$(date): Backup Successful" >> /home/zero/Backup/backup.log
        # remove file once it has been sent to remote server
        rm -f $filename
    else
        echo "$(date): Error occurred while sending backup to remote server" >> /home/zero/Backup/backup.log
    fi
else
    # if file is not found display error msg 
    echo "$(date): No encrypted file found" >> /home/zero/Backup/backup.log
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    send=scp $filename root@178.79.148.186:/root/Backup
```

You forgot the [command substitution syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) here, and it's trying to execute `$filename` as a command.
I presume at this point that `filename= /home/zero/Backup/backup_20230731_1251.tar.gz.gpg` and it doesn't have *execute* permissions.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt't use command substitution syntax as it just returns "scp".